# Use of numbers in descriptions

Tags: grammar, counters

So far I've only learned how to use numbers in the context of counting e.g.
このピザは 5枚ある (this pizza has five slices).

How do I express it in the following way:

> This is a **five-slice pizza**

I would naively guess at "これは5枚のピザがある”, but I've not seen a counter used to modify a noun like that before.

Secondly, kind-of in the reverse direction how would I express the part in bold below:

> (Please exit from) **the front five coaches** of this ten coach train

Hmm, I tried to construct this sentence but it just made me more sure that my guess for the first part of the question was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Though I don't know if this answers your question:)

> This is **a five-slice pizza**.

You normally say it as:

> これは、**５枚[切]{ぎ}りの**ピザです。
>   or
>   このピザは、５枚切りです。

---

> (Please exit from) **the front five coaches** of this ten coach train.

I think you'd normally say it as:

> １０[両]{りょう}[編成]{へんせい}の電車の**[前]{まえ}５両** / **前の５両** (から降りてください。/ 下車してください。/ お降りください。)